# Query that finds connection (friend, friend of friend) too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

If two users are friends, I have one entry in the "friends" table for them like this:

```
   table: friends
   ------------------------
   uid1           uid2
   332            333
```

Now let's say a new user (with uid=100) joins. My app finds the users near her, and then tries to show their connection (fb friends, friends of friends, etc.) to her. I use this query for this purpose:

```
           SELECT (fr.id IS NOT NULL)+(f2.id IS NOT NULL)*2+(fr.id IS NULL AND f2.id IS NULL)*3 AS connection
           FROM users u
           LEFT JOIN friends AS fr ON ((fr.uid1='100' AND fr.uid2=u.uid) OR (fr.uid1=u.uid AND fr.uid2='100'))
           LEFT JOIN (friends AS f1, friends AS f2) ON fr.id IS NULL AND
           (
            (f1.uid1='100' AND f1.uid2=f2.uid1 AND f2.uid2=u.uid) OR
            (f1.uid2='100' AND f1.uid1=f2.uid1 AND f2.uid2=u.uid) OR
            (f1.uid2='100' AND f1.uid1=f2.uid2 AND f2.uid1=u.uid) OR
            (f1.uid1='100' AND f1.uid2=f2.uid2 AND f2.uid1=u.uid)
           ) 
           WHERE [location near her]
```

This query will find people near the new user, and for each one the value of "connection" will be 1 if friends with the new user, 2 if they have a common friend, and 3 otherwise.

The query used to work okay but now that I have just a little more users (10,000) it has become very slow (takes 10 seconds to find the type of connection for just 10 people near the new user).
Is there something I'm doing completely wrong in my query or database scheme? I know that defining indices will make things faster but still I think taking 10 seconds for such simple query is very long. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Could you explain how can this query find peoples ? It prints only a sequence of numbers 1,2,3,3,3,2,2,3 etc. See this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49fe8/3 it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: First, thanks for creating the sqlfiddle. The query I mentioned was just an example.. In reality, it would be http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49fe8/4
(so it will select uid and connection type relative to the new user, for each user)

Comment: Can you please post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT (fr.id IS NOT NULL) ...` (that is, add an `explain` in front of the query.

Comment: You do have both a (uid1,uid2) and a (uid2,uid1) index on the friends table, right?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on sqlfiddle to stick with your question.
This is what I suggest :

- Do not use `OR` condition in `left join`, it's a performance killer, better to do 2 joins or more than using `OR`
- Do not use `fr.id IS NULL` in 2nd `left join` (Performance killer), instead use it in select part : `(fr.id IS NOT NULL)+(fr.id IS NULL AND f2.id IS NOT NULL)*2`
- Use `CASE WHEN [cond] THEN [type_connection] ELSE 3 END` to show 1/2/3 type of connection (More readable)

Here is my suggested code (exemple : new user with uid=1) :

```
SELECT
    u.uid
    ,CASE
        WHEN directFriend.frUid IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        WHEN commonFriend.frUid IS NOT NULL THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END as connection
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT 
                u.uid as frUid
            FROM 
                users u
                LEFT JOIN friends as fr1
                    ON fr1.uid1='1' 
                    AND fr1.uid2=u.uid
                LEFT JOIN friends as fr2
                    ON fr2.uid1=u.uid 
                    AND fr2.uid2='1'
            WHERE
                fr1.uid2 IS NOT NULL 
                OR fr2.uid1 IS NOT NULL) as directFriend
        ON directFriend.frUid = u.uid
    LEFT JOIN(
            SELECT 
                CASE 
                    WHEN common1.uid2 IS NOT NULL THEN common1.uid2
                    WHEN common2.uid1 IS NOT NULL THEN common2.uid1
                END as frUid
            FROM 
                users u
                LEFT JOIN friends as fr1
                    ON fr1.uid1='1' 
                    and fr1.uid2=u.uid
                LEFT JOIN friends as fr2
                    ON fr2.uid2='1' 
                    and fr2.uid1=u.uid 
                LEFT JOIN friends as common1
                    ON common1.uid1 = fr1.uid2
                    AND common1.uid1 = u.uid
                LEFT JOIN friends as common2
                    ON common2.uid2 = fr2.uid1
                    AND common2.uid2 = u.uid
            WHERE
                common1.uid2 IS NOT NULL 
                OR common2.uid1 IS NOT NULL) as commonFriend
    ON commonFriend.frUid = u.uid
```

[Here is the sqlfiddle demo used](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49fe8/74)

Hope it helps :)